# Generate a code by replacing user input based on an associative array

Tags: php, replace, substring, translation

I have a 16-character, input string composed of hexadecimal characters.  I need to isolate the last two characters, then replace the first character using an associative lookup/map, then extend the string from two to four characters by repeating the characters.

My sample input is:

```
$atcode = '11F5796B61690196';
```

My associative array is:

```
$sub1 = [
    '0' => '2',
    '1' => '3',
    '2' => '0',
    '3' => '1',
    '4' => '6',
    '5' => '7',
    '7' => '5',
    '8' => 'A',
    '9' => 'B',
    'A' => '8',
    'B' => '9',
    'C' => 'E',
    'D' => 'F',
    'E' => 'C',
    'F' => 'D'
];
```

The isolated characterd should be `9` and `6`.

The desired result is: `B6B6`

This is the code so far:

```
$codearray = str_split($atcode);
    
//select the 15th digit from $codearray and name it $one
$one = $codearray[14];
    
//create an associative array and name it $sub1
$sub1 = array('0' => '2', '1' => '3', '3' => '1', 'D' => 'F', '4' => '6', '5' => '7', '7' => '5', '8' => 'A', '9' => 'B', 'A' => '8', 'B' => '9', 'C' => 'E', '2' => '0', 'E' => 'C', 'F' => 'D');
    
//search through $sub1, determine which value is equivalent to $one, and select its equivalency from the key to value pairs
$codeone = array_replace($one, $sub1);
    
//select the 16th digit from $codearray and name it $two
$two = $codearray[15];
    
echo "$codeone", "$two";
```

However, I am just getting a blank page.

Comment: ``array_replace($one, $sub1)``, here $one should be an array, not string !

Comment: You should have a lot of errors rather than a blank page - demo: https://3v4l.org/vI3TK . Although possibly you haven't shown us some of the code, e.g. where `$atcode` is defined?? Enable PHP error reporting in your development environment - without error reporting how do you ever expect to find basic faults in your code? Enabling that should be the first step when setting up your environment for development and testing. (And if you're testing this on a public site directly well...don't do that, use a local development environment.)

Comment: Unless I've missed some nuances here, couldn't this code be simplified to `echo $sub1[$atcode[14]] . $atcode[15];`?

Comment: You should at the very least be seeing a `Uncaught TypeError: array_replace(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given` error. That's because `$one` is a string, not an array. It's unclear how you expect to use an array function to replace parts of a string? [Read the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php).

Comment: Not sure why the SQL was removed from the question as it is one of the main parts of why you aren't getting anything out of your code.

Comment: I removed extraneous portions of code so that the narrow task of string processing was the focus.  If the asker needs to know how to access a single value from a database table, we certainly have duplicates for that task.  I don't believe we have a duplicate for the 3-step mutation.

Comment: You also removed the text *fetch the user input code from mysql database*, as this basically didn't work it is no wonder the process didn't give any results - something the question now completely ommits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abandon most of that code.

Extract the last two characters, translate the first, then repeat them.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NphYr))

```
var_export(
    str_repeat(
        strtr(
            $atcode[14],
            '012345789ABCDEF',
            '2301675AB89EFCD'
        ) . $atcode[15],
        2
    )
);
```

Or if you want to use the associative array: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/5ZJIv)

```
var_export(
    str_repeat(
        strtr($atcode[14], $sub1) . $atcode[15],
        2
    )
);
```

Here's an alternative, for the regex lovers: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/9OsSD)

```
var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/.*(.)(.)/',
        fn($m) => str_repeat(strtr($m[1], $sub1) . $m[2], 2),
        $atcode
    )
);
```

Comment: Why bother to no-comment dv the most concise and robust answer on the page?  Just being malicious? You don't think I'm going to delete the best answer on the page, right? Are you trying to make it harder for researchers to find the best answer?

Comment: your second solution which uses associative arrays works best for my situation. Any advice on how I can refer to the generated code?

Comment: What do you mean? Set the generated text to a variable instead of printing it?

Comment: `$newCode = str_repeat(strtr($atcode[14], $sub1) . $atcode[15], 2);`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, apppreciated

Answer (score 0):

Once you have initialised `$atcode`, I suggest you could simplify your code to this:

```php
$sub1 = array('0' => '2', '1' => '3', '3' => '1', 'D' => 'F', '4' => '6', '5' => '7', '7' => '5', '8' => 'A', '9' => 'B', 'A' => '8', 'B' => '9', 'C' => 'E', '2' => '0', 'E' => 'C', 'F' => 'D');
echo str_repeat($sub1[$atcode[14]] . $atcode[15], 2);
```

Comment: This may cause trouble if the second last character is a 6.

Answer (score 0):

Change $codeone = array_replace($one, $sub1); to $codeone = $sub1[$one];

```
$codearray = str_split("11F5796B61690196");
    
    
    $one = $codearray[14];

// Create an associative array and name it $sub1
$sub1 = array('0' => '2', '1' => '3', '3' => '1', 'D' => 'F', '4' => '6', '5' => '7', '7' => '5', '8' => 'A', '9' => 'B', 'A' => '8', 'B' => '9', 'C' => 'E', '2' => '0', 'E' => 'C', 'F' => 'D');

// Search through $sub1, determine which value is equivalent to $one, and select its equivalency from the key to value pairs
$codeone = $sub1[$one];

// Select the 16th digit from $codearray and name it $two
$two = $codearray[15];

// Output the 4-digit code
echo $codeone . $two.$codeone . $two;
```

This should give B6B6

Comment: PHP will complain if the second last character is a 6 -- which is not an existing key in the lookup array.